# Mysql SELECT and COUNT WHERE

Tags: mysql

I have two tables (lets call them cases and users) structured something like this: Cases

```
ID|status      |user_id
__|____________|_______  
1 |Open        |6
2 |Closed      |9
3 |Incomplete  |9
```

Users:

```
ID| 
__|_____
 6|
 9|
```

I would like to select a count for the id as well as a count for each one of the status fields.

Currently I have tried:

```
SELECT COUNT(c.id), COUNT(
(SELECT status from cases where status = 'Open')),
COUNT(
(SELECT status from cases where status = 'Closed')),
COUNT(
(SELECT status from cases where status = 'Incomplete'))
FROM cases as c
JOIN users as u on u.id = c.user_id
```

I am getting an error of query returning more than one row.

This is what I am trying to achieve

```
ID| Open | Closed | Incomplete |user_id
__|______|________|____________|__________
 2|0     |1       |1           |9
```

RECAP:  A count for each user id that counts how many id's, and a count for each status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this with `sum`

```
SELECT COUNT(c.id), 
SUM(c.status = 'Open') Open ,
SUM(c.status = 'Closed') Closed ,
SUM(c.status = 'Incomplete') Incomplete,
u.id user_id
FROM cases as c
JOIN users as u on u.id = c.user_id
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: This seems like such a reasonable answer.  It is just really hard to tell if this actually answers the question.